# Should I use several languages or only one language in my fictional world?

Tags: culture, language

I'm a new member in your forum, and since I want to success in my project to create a great fictional world, I would need some advices.

Since I intend to "remix" our real world, I have to create fictional peoples and fictional cultures based on real peoples and real cultures.

Thus, I wonder if I should use several languages or only one language. If I use several languages, do you think that it would be appropriate if I use real languages? I ask this question because I read in some articles that if I create fictional versions of real peoples or if fictional peoples were too much based on real peoples, that could be considered as irrespectful, especially for marginalized cultures and peoples.

Otherwise, I could have to create fictional languages, but it could be too much complex.

I hope that you would be able to help me on my issue.

Thanks you all for your answers!

Comment: What are you planning to use your fictional world for?  If it is for storytelling then having communication difficulties (between your pov characters and the people they meet during their travels) could be a useful plot tool.  If it is background for a video or board game then multiple languages would probably be overkill.

Comment: I want to create a website in which I will make an encyclopedia similar to Wikipedia, but I could also create videos and images about my fictional world.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This problem was solved three thousand years ago.

[Homer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homer), in his [*Iliad*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iliad) and [*Odyssey*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odyssey), had to decide what to do with the Trojans, the [Phaeacians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheria), the [Lotus-Eaters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotus-eaters), and other exotic aliens.

He solved the problem in the simplest way possible: everybody speaks Greek. The readers (or, rather, in that time, the *listeners*) of course understood that in real life the exotic aliens spoke exotic alien languages; but, for the purpose of telling the story, those languages are seamlessly translated into Greek.

So by and large do not use exotic alien languages in their exotic alien form. You may speak about them, you may comment on the impression they make, on the ease or difficulty of learning them: but do not use them as such, unless you are writing a story which is actually about the languages themselves.

For example:

> The door opened before he could knock. A young girl of about ten years of age performed a charming curtsey and welcomed him. The sonorous vowels of the Phaeacian language made him think of an Italian song, especially since she was using a rather old-fashioned semi-formal form of speech, with  a sing-songy intonation and the word endings clearly articulated. He expressed his gratitude in the same language, then, bowing a little to come nearer to her height, he asked, in a whispered voice, what was a suitable title for her?

(That's an extemporaneous composition, not a quotation from any particular book.)

What you *may* do, if, in your opinion, it helps with the story telling, is to sprinkle here and there a few words and short phrases in the alien tongues, making certain that the reader can grasp their meaning efortlessly. *Do not* use a real foreign language for this; people actually know foreign languages, both ancient and modern, and will wonder how come the exotic aliens speak Church Slavonic with an East Slavic accent? (Modern languages add the even more thorny problem of what to do when the book is translated into that language...) For this purpose, you may either invent words, or, more easily, mechanically transform some foreign language which you know.

As a practical example, consider [S. M. Stirling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M._Stirling)'s series [*The General*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_General_series), telling the thrilling adventures of Raj Whitehall on planet Bellevue. Several languages are spoken in that world, all presumably descended from Earth languages; Raj himself speaks Sponglish, which is rendered as plain English in the book; other people speak other languages, and the relationships between them are commented upon, but their words are also rendered as plain English. Occasionally, one or two words in those othe other languages appear in the text, for local color; Spanjol is rendered as mangled Spanish (with the comment that it is quite close to Sponglish), Paytoiz is rendered as very mangled French, Namerique appears as barely recognizable mangled English. The only unmangled language is the Arabic spoken by the people of the Colony, which is explainable in universe because they are for-real Muslims -- the only Earth religion to have survived. The English language itself seems to be called Old Namerique, and only very well-educated people are said to understand it.

At the other extreme are of course Tolkien's Middle Earth books, where the exotic alien languages are convincingly elaborated; but even Tolkien writes plain English and keeps the words and phrases in exotic languages to a minimum, just enough to give a flavor. (Do not try to emulate him unless you are willing to spend a few intense years learning and applying historical linguistics.)

Comment: What I understand is that I could create fictional languages based on real languages. Probably that I could create fictional languages that will merger two languages. Probably that I should read how I can do to create fictional languages.

Comment: @RochTristan: You should create no more than *a few words* in the fictional languages. Use them sparingly, like a spice when cooking. In most cases, not even those few words are needed. There are plenty of great books where the fictional languages are never exemplified in their native form.

Comment: I don't know a single word of Phaecian, but know a bit about the language. It is a word-ending inflected language whose casual speakers do not fully articulate the endings but experts do in formal speech. That is similar to late Latin, but the viewpoint character is familiar with Italian song and does not hear Phaecian as an Italian dialect, so it is not actually late Latin. It is sufficiently formal that one cannot properly address another without knowing their title. You can write about a language, and about people using it, without creating a single word of the language.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: Excellent! (Minor notes: Many people are familiar with the sound of Italian songs without knowing Italian at all. A language can lose its word endings without necessarily those endings being morphological inflections; such phonetic erosion is what made Latin /'lakte-/, /'ok(u)lu-/ or /pari'eːte-/ into French /lɛ/, /œj/ or /paʁwa/.)

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan - it is really great that you added that piece about needing a title to speak the language.  I wondered about the question that ended that snippet AlexP composed and now I understand.

Comment: The key thing to remember about Tolkien is that there are a few people who have studied one or more of his constructed languages, but there are many, many more who have read and enjoyed Lord of the Rings. He invented languages because that was the sort of thing he did for fun, not because inventing the languages was necessary for the books.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan - That's true. And in fact, Tolkien himself wrote that it was his LotR that was created to serve as a _mythos_ behind his conlangs, and surely not the conlangs for LotR. Also, he wrote that the obvious reason why Esperanto failed to become the Global Language was the complete absence of any _mythos_ behind Esperanto.

Answer (score 2):

Only add complexity if it will add something to your readers' experience.

They can add a lot. Tolkien used languages brilliantly to express the cultural richness of his world.

But using one language will greatly simplify things and keep the plot moving without the need for translators and translation all the time. What would the benefit be?

Comment: Tolkien made a lot of background fluff with his languages, but they appear very briefly in his stories. He even made multiple kinds of orthography that didn't appear in anything but a few illustrations and were entirely unnecessary to the stories. He did it because he enjoyed doing that stuff, not because it was required or even important.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the forum. It is important when asking questions here to try to keep them well focused, but I will try to answer.

If your world had a recent populating event such as a colonization spacecraft landing then it would seem likely they would use just one language. If you are taking about a worldwide civilization that has grown u over millennia then multiple languages would be much more appropriate.

I wouldn't worry about being disrespectful with respect to languages. Languages are supposed to be used to communicate. It would probably be more disrespectful to forget them entirely.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you are asking about two things. 
First would your world contain more than one language? 
The second point I'm not exactly sure what do you mean.

Anyway the first one we can think about.
It depends. 
If you want to have a real diverse world that simulates the complexity of the real world then obviously you have to include different languages, and you might even add different dialects or accents.
However why only have those things because of how our world evolved and changed overtime. 
So if your world does not have similar "linguistic evolution" then you can simplify. 
But to what extent? Single language culture perhaps. 
Like you have kingdom/culture X sharing language X. 
Kingdom/culture Y sharing language Y.

Now that is not the end of it. For example of you have an empire spanning an entire continent then you can have one language used there or even enforced. 
Then depending on the empire the other languages might be tolerated but not used or even banned. But at least you can have an official language for business.

But for added complexity then you can think of some real world examples. 
For example I read that the Russian nobility would use French, the Roman nobility of the empire would use Greek, the church uses Latin...etc.

From that you can add layers of complexity by thinking of the natural interaction between the people/languages of the world.

Example. Empire A is a juggernaut of material powers. They trampled small country B.
However country B was so advanced in science and literature that the nobility of the empire adopted the language of country B, Rome and Greece basically. 
However the empire still used its own language for official business. 
But within the borders of the empire there is a whole bunch of countries with many having their own language that is still used in their everyday life. 
So an aspiring noble from a country knows his own language, but for official business uses the language of the empire and on top of all that learns the language of country B that the nobility thinks is just so sophsticated. 
Heck. You might even add a "high" and "lower" tier to the official language with the higher being the formal state business and writing type of deal and the "lower" as the everyday language used by the people.

But again it's all about the context.